# Status only changing to ROLLBACK_COMPLETE from CREATE_IN_PROGRESS while trying to create a stack on CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am simply trying to create a stack(Name: wordpress) on cloud formation via the AWS console (region N. virginia) by specifying an 
amazon S3 template URL (https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsinaction/chapter2/template.json) and putting the keyName as "mykey" in the parameter section. Also, I'm providing values for the Key(system) and Value(wordpress) fields in tag section. Every time after I am clicking the create button on Review Page, the status is transitioning to ROLLBACK_COMPLETE from CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. The status reason showing is "Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name KeyName does not exist. Rollback requested by user".

I know I am missing out something very prominent but can't figure out what. Any help on this would be great, I am trying to replicate an example from oreily amazon web service in action, chapter 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you do not have a key pair - 'my.pem' in your account. You need to replace it with a key pair name you have in your account. You can check for the key pairs in your account using AWS EC2 Console and checking 'Key Pairs' tab.

Note: You don't need to supply .pem, in above case key name will be just my

Comment: Thanks, Missed out creating a key pair "mykey". It's done now. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues when creating stack then check StackStatusReason

```
StackStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: ...
```

some resources already exist, rename or delete them then create stack again.

`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name <> --disable-rollback`

hope it's helpful!